# Using data and functions from other Rmd files when Knitting in r-markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am building my first large project. It is so large that a single .Rmd file becomes much to long to work with.

I have therefore split my work into several .Rmd files

Their function is implied by their names:

- 01_Import_and_clenase.Rmd
- 02_Functions-Rmd
- 03_Test_of_Assumptions.Rmd

"03_Test_of_Assumptions.Rmd" uses data from 01 and plots it via functions from 02. It all works fine when I run it inside Rstudio, but when I try to knitt 03 is doesn´t work because it can´t find the functions or the data.

Is there a way to make the 03 document read 01 and 02 when I knitt?

Comment: 1. If it's only functions you don't really need `Rmd` file. At the begging of `03_Test_of_Assumptions.Rmd` add `source("functions.R")` and you will get plotting functions; 2. It's a good practice  to save your data (eg, raw, cleaned). `01.Rmd`  could import raw data and save cleaned data which will be imported by `03.Rmd`. Not to run cleaning twice you can use: `if (file.exists("cleaned.RDS")) {}`

Comment: Why are the 2 first files .rmd? Do they have to be documents or can they be just scripts?

Comment: PoGibas and Dror - Thank you for your replies.   The first two files are only .Rmd files because I like the workflow with chunks and being able to control parts of the code through these. If that is going to keep me from knitting 03, then I will reformat them as suggested by PoGibas.  Also I will read some more about Projects it looks like I have missed some fundamental points on how to use R-Markdown and projects.

Comment: If it's only code and not report you don't need `Rmd`. The only useful option in `knit` for plain code that I can think of is `eval=TRUE/FALSE`, but if you don't want code to be evaluated just comment it out.

Comment: So in general I should only have one .Rmd file for every project?

Comment: In my work I have many `functions.R` files and many `import.R`, `clean.R`, `model.R` files and when it comes to reports I prefer to have only a couple of those (`plot.Rmd`, `summaryData.Rmd`). But this is my own preference.

Comment: I find `knitr::read_chunk` very useful for allowing several rmd files to access the same code